# Getting rid of namespace added to the inner element <i>,<b>, <mpval>

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

Namespace getting added to the inner element `<i>,<b>, <mpval>`. I want to get rid of this namespace.

My XML:

```
 <Container xmlns="http://www.sss.org/schema/"   
  xmlns:meta="http://www.sss.org/schema/tangier/metadata">
 <cs-properties> 
 My Parent level text 1
 <mp>  
 text1 of first child <b> in bold</b>  
 <mpval>36-37</mpval> 
 text2 of child <i> in italic </i> 
 </mp>
 My Parent level text2 in <i>italic</i> also in <b>bold </b>
</cs-properties>
</Container>
```

When I apply below XSL, I get namespace added to `<i>` element. Want to get rid of it.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:sub="http://www.sss.org/schema"                
exclude-result-prefixes="xsl sub">

<xsl:variable name="ns" select="'http://www.sss.org/schema/'" />

<xsl:output indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="inlineElements" select="'b','i','sub','sup'"/>


<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
<xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match="sub:cs-properties">
<!--<properties xmlns= "{$ns}">-->
<xsl:element name="cs-properties" namespace="{$ns}" >
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::text() or self::node()  
 [name()=$inlineElements]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()=true()">
        <parenttext>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" copy-namespaces="no" />
        </parenttext>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
  <!--</properties>-->
  </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="sub:mp|sub:abs-max">
 <xsl:element name="{name()}">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="self::text() or self::node()
 [name()=$inlineElements]">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()=true()">
        <childtext>
          <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" copy-namespaces="no"/>
        </childtext>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!--<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>-->
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()" copy-namespaces="no"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
 </xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>    
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<Container xmlns="http://www.sss.org/schema"    
xmlns:meta="http://www.sss.org/schema/tangier/metadata"><cs-properties><parenttext   
xmlns=""> &#xD;
 My Parent level text 1&#xD;
 </parenttext><mp xmlns=""><childtext>  &#xD;
 text1 of first child <b xmlns="http://www.sss.org/schema"> in 
bold</b></childtext><mpval xmlns="http://www.sss.org/schema">36- 
37</mpval><childtext> &#xD;
 text2 of child <i xmlns="http://www.sss.org/schema"> in italic </i>
</childtext></mp><parenttext xmlns="">&#xD;
My Parent level text2 in <i 
xmlns="http://www.sss.org/schema">italic</i> also in <b 
xmlns="http://www.sss.org/schema">bold </b></parenttext></cs-
properties></Container>
```

Comment: Since `schema/chemical/substance` does not appear anywhere in the original XML nor in the XSL, I assume that the cause for the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: I have corrected the result. Please hlpe.

Comment: I have managed to remove namespace. but somehow my xsl is not reading further child elements of <cs-properties> .Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the `<parenttext xmlns="">` either by using `<parenttext xmlns="http://www.sss.org/schema/">` in your markup or by putting `xmlns="http://www.sss.org/schema/"` on the styleheet's root element. The latter would affect all result elements which might be needed if you have them in more places in the stylesheet.

Comment: I have managed to remove namespace as per your suggestion . but somehow my xsl is not reading further child elements(at level of <mp>) of <cs-properties> . Please help

Comment: I think if my answer solved the problems with the namespaces but you have another problem then you should post a new question, providing the necessary details like input sample, stylesheet, output you want and the one you get.